# I am trying to click a button that is inside nested divs using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The structure looks like this:

```
<div class="edit-post-header">
<div class="edit-post-header__settings">
<button type="button" aria-disabled="false" class="components-button editor-post-publish-button editor-post-publish-button__button is-primary">Publish</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to click it like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='edit-post-header']//div[@class='edit-post-header__settings']//button[@class='editor-post-publish-button__button']").click()
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Any reason you want xpath explicitly? Why not query by CSS selector with class name, as the class looks quite specific? E.g. **browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.components-button.editor-post-publish-button.editor-post-publish-button__button.is-primary').click()**

Answer (score 1):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

xpath that you should check :

```
//button[text()='Publish']
```

if it is unique, please use below code to click :

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Publish']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Publish']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```